# How to add field from another field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is my code in adding field to Mongo Shell

```
db.testing.aggregate([ 
           {$addFields: 
                {location: 
                     {type: "Point", 
                     coordinates: ["$long", "$lat"]
                     }
                }
           }, {$out: "testing"}])
```

I also wanted to add a default value when a column doesn't have long and lat field and convert the string to number.

My Database:

```
column1
test: "test" 


column2
long: "1111"
lat: "1111"
test: "test2"

column3
test:"test3"
long:"2222"
lat: "2222"
```

Expected Output

```
column1
test: "test"
location: Object
    type: "Point",
    coordinates: Array
     0: 14.00 //default value
     1: 15.00 //default value

column2
    test: "test2"
    location: Object
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: Array
         0: 1111 
         1: 1111 


column3
    test: "test3"
    location: Object
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: Array
         0: 2222 
         1: 2222
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$cond` to create value or retrieve number
- `$unset` to remove **long** and **lat**

If you want everything with **.00** you can use `$trunc` but normally people just use them without trailing **0**.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JQ2f4Wsrd7x)

```
var pipeline = [
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          {
            "$cond": [
              {
                "$eq": [
                  {
                    "$type": "$long"
                  },
                  "missing"
                ]
              },
              14.00,
              {
                "$toDouble": "$long"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "$cond": [
              {
                "$eq": [
                  {
                    "$type": "$lat"
                  },
                  "missing"
                ]
              },
              15.00,
              {
                "$toDouble": "$lat"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: [
      "lat",
      "long"
    ]
  },
    {
        "$out" : "testing"
    }
]
db.testing.aggregate(pipeline)
```

Comment: Hi, may I know where did "missing" come from?

Comment: @PinkyPromise yes, when the field does not exist `$type` returns "missing"

Comment: Hi, may I ask again?